# Count number of files with .extention

Tags: files

The question already exists in 7 different threads, but everytime I do what they say to do, it doesn't work and show me total 0 or other bullshit, help!

Comment: I need to know for a little homework what is the command to count the number of files with .conf extension in my drive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  AskUbuntu is not  "Do My Homework" service. Please put in at least some effort and show some work next time you ask a question

Comment: @Serg at least the OP states it's for homework. Many aren't so candid. And the pupil did try 7 other threads which deserves an `A` for effort even if the result was an `F` :) Should I flag a mod to challenge and reopen the question if it's closed as you suggested last night to me :D  It should be flagged for vulgarity though...

Comment: Use your discretion :) Personally, i think just saying "I tried 7 other threads" isn't enough, at least provide which answers, or links to those threads.

Comment: I think OP should reopen this question this time being a bit more elaborate and less vulgar. Steeldriver's comment makes it worth it!

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
find ~ -iname '*.conf' | wc -l
```

Replace `~` with the directory inside which to count the `*.conf` files (recursively).

The `find` command searches for files with names matching the case insensitive globbing pattern `*.conf` inside `~` recursively. It prints each resulting file name in a single line.

`wc -l` counts the number of lines of its input.

Comment: If we're going to teach the young 'uns right, we should probably  be suggesting `-printf 'x' | wc -c` (which is safe for all legal filenames - i.e. doesn't double count files whose names contain a newline)